# Deployment on GCP compute instance failed why pushing changes from Gitlab

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ssh-keys

Am a newbie to Gitlab, hoping to find help here.

I have a VM in GCP that is running debian linux.
I am using Gitlab to push changes to that VM.
For the prerequisites, I have the SSH keys generated and added to Gitlab.

This is how my gitlab-ci.yml looks like

```
before_script:
 - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sshpass

deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Staging
  only:
    - stage
  script:
    - ls
    - sshpass -V
    - export SSHPASS=$USER_PASS 
    - sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r . xxxxxx@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/datastore/test
```

But when I merge a change I get the following error

Output from pipeline job

```
$ ls
test
test2
test2-merge
$ sshpass -V
sshpass 1.06
(C) 2006-2011 Lingnu Open Source Consulting Ltd.
(C) 2015-2016 Shachar Shemesh
This program is free software, and can be distributed under the terms of the GPL
See the COPYING file for more information.

Using "assword" as the default password prompt indicator.
$ export SSHPASS=$USER_PASS
$ sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r . xxxxxx@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/datastore/test
***Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xxx.xx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).***
lost connection
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Using "assword"? Is that expected?

Comment: yes, that is what sshpass displays. I had the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have the right ssh keys and copied them without cutting off any characters. Can you connect manually with those keys? E.g., add them to your local .ssh/config and try to ssh into the VM.

Comment: That was a good suggestion. I tried and I get the exact same error. I used a pretty standard ssh key generation method.

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your.email@example.com" -b 4096
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: I also checked the permissions - i dont see any issue there either
drwx------  .ssh
-rw-r--r--  id_rsa.pub
-rw------- id_rsa

Comment: Ah OK, then it's probably a firewall issue. Are ssh connections allowed on your VM? One more thing to try first: connect via the Cloud Console's SSH button. https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances